# Add controller to all pages UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

How to add an UI controller to all pages of the app? For example, having the same SplitView controller with navigation menu in Pane on all pages without copying its xaml code? Or maybe changing App.xaml in some way?

Or, as a second option, is it possible to create a UserControl that contains SplitView and put all other views on this page inside it Content? I mean, how to put views into the UserControl in xaml (or even in code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom `RootControl` which derives from `UserControl` class and which contains the root `Frame`

```
    <SplitView DisplayMode="CompactOverlay">
      <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Home"
                          Width="50"
                          MinWidth="50"
                          Click="OnHomeClicked"
                          />
            <AppBarButton Icon="Shop"
                          Width="50"
                          MinWidth="50"
                          Click="OnShopClicked"/>
            <AppBarButton Icon="Setting"
                          MinWidth="50"
                          Width="50"
                          Click="OnSettingsClicked"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </SplitView.Pane>
      <SplitView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Frame x:Name="rootFrame"/>

            <!--Put your hamburger button here-->

        </Grid>
      </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
```

Rewrite **OnLauched**:

```
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {

        var rootControl = Window.Current.Content as RootControl;

        if (rootControl == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootControl = new RootControl();

            rootControl.RootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootControl;
        }

        if (rootControl.RootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootControl.RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

and you can manage you actions from code-behind or `ViewModel` for navigation and other actions

```
    public sealed partial class RootControl : UserControl
    {
        private Type currentPage;

        public RootControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            RootFrame.Navigated += OnNavigated;
        }

        private void OnNavigated(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            currentPage = e.SourcePageType;
        }

        public Frame RootFrame
        {
            get
            {
                return rootFrame;
             }
        }

        private void OnHomeClicked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }

        private void OnShopClicked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             Navigate(typeof(StorePage));
        }

        private void OnSettingsClicked(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
        }

        private void Navigate(Type pageSourceType)
        {
            if (currentPage != pageSourceType)
            {
                RootFrame.Navigate(pageSourceType);
            }
        }
    }
```

[Download](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhDVarJnnlKKr-QsMZ_h2c7C2NHPYQ) the sample and look how it works

Comment: Hi
It feels like your example is what I need but your download link does not work

Comment: how to fix statusbar showing over the frame without hiding it?

 https://1drv.ms/i/s!AnzkwdhwRbbno9dnRGLJTkTO4xmaOQ

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're after something like what Jerry Nixon suggests in [this article here](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/04/implementing-hamburger-button-with.html).

The essential idea is that instead of a Frame control hosting all of your app's content, you create a "Shell" (in the article's case, made of a SplitView, but really, it could probably be anything), which has some content of its own, *as well as* a Frame control (which then hosts the rest of your content).